# HOW - SOAP Webservices Automation Testing?

Tags: soap, automation

What are the ways/tools/softwares that can be used to automate the testing of SOAP WebServices.

Manual testing can be done using SOAP UI but how to do automation testing ? Any links? Please share.

Answer (score -1):

Web Service automation testing can be done through UFT and Selenium as well. We have implement the same in our project.